# how to create mysql database and schema and insert data that will automatically be shown on phpmyadmin with docker-compose file

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose, phpmyadmin

i am trying to create mysql database and schema and insert data into the database with docker-compose file.

In the docker-compose file I have phpmyadmin which ought to show that the database and schema are created and populated with data.

Below is my docker-compose file and you will find the mysqldb service with mysql as the container name and linked to phpmyadmin service via network called backend.

I don't know what is wrong with the settings why it is not giving me the expected behaviour

```
version: '3.9'
services:
    nginx:
        image: nginx:latest
        volumes:
            - "./docker/etc/nginx/default.template.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf"
            - "./docker/etc/nginx/ssl:/etc/ssl"
            - "./:/var/www/html:cached"
        ports:
            - "8080:80"
            - "3000:443"
        restart: always
        networks:
            - backend
    PHP:
        image: nanoninja/php-fpm:latest
        restart: always
        ports:
            - "9000:9000"
        volumes:
            - "./docker/etc/php/php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/php.ini"
            - "./:/var/www/html:cached"
        networks:
            - backend
    phpmyadmin:
        image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
        container_name: phpmyadmin
        ports:
            - "8000:80"
        environment:
            - PMA_ARBITRARY=1
            - PMA_HOST=mysql
        restart: always
        networks:
            - backend
    mysqldb:
        image: mysql:latest
        container_name: MySQL
        restart: always
        environment:
            - MYSQL_HOST=mysql
            - MYSQL_DATABASE=sakila
            - MYSQL_ROOT_USER=root
            - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
        ports:
            - "8989:3306"
        volumes:
            - ./docker/etc/mysql/1_create_db.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/1_create_db.sql:ro
            - ./docker/etc/mysql/2_create_schema.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/2_create_schema.sql:ro 
            - ./docker/etc/mysql/3_insert_data.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/3_insert_data.sql:ro
            - ./docker/data/db/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
        networks:
            - backend
        command: ["--character-set-server=utf8mb4", "--collation-server=utf8mb4_general_ci", "--skip-character-set-client-handshake"]
    sphinx:
        build:
            context: ./docker/etc/sphinx
            dockerfile: Dockerfile-sphinx
        container_name: sphinx
        restart: always
        ports:
            - "9311:9306"
        volumes:
            - "./docker/etc/sphinx/conf:/sphinx/conf"
            - "./docker/data/index/sphinx/runs:/sphinx/runs"
            - "./docker/data/index/sphinx/logs:/sphinx/logs"
            - "./docker/data/index/sphinx/binlog:/sphinx/binlog"
        entrypoint: ["/bin/sh", "/sphinx/conf/entrypoint.sh"]
        networks:
            - backend
networks:
    backend: {}
```

I have been searching on how to solve this problem, especially with docker-compose file and i have tried different variant of directories to mount the .sql files

```
1st variant uses

volumes:
    - ./sqlfile.sql:/data/application/sqlfile.sql


2nd variant uses

volumes:
    - ./docker/etc/mysql/1_create_db.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/1_create_db.sql:ro
```

I have tried both but none is working, whenever i check http://localhost:8000 and login with username: root and password: root.

I am using sakila database from [this git link](https://github.com/jOOQ/sakila/tree/main/mysql-sakila-db)

After running the command below

```
sudo docker-compose up
```

I am expecting to see sakila created in the list of databases in phpmyadmin screenshot below

[image]

But it seems my docker-compose file is not working.

Please I need help or hint on how to solve this problem